# Can MP3 be sent to SPI of Adafruit Music Maker Arduino shield instead of from its SD card?

Tags: shields, communication, spi

Can uncompressed MP3 audio data be sent from Arduino board, by SPI, to Adafruit Music Maker shield instead of from the SD card on the Music Maker?

Instead of using SD card on Music Maker board, I want to send the compressed MP3 data from a Particle Photon board on the Particle shield shield, by SPI, to the VS1053B codec chip on Music Maker board, and then to amplifier for speakers.

Particle Shield Shield is attached to Particle Photon board, which has STM32F205RGY6 120Mhz ARM Cortex M3.

Particle Photon board uses its WiFi to receive uncompressed MP3.

Comment: There's no such thing as "uncompressed MP3". MP3 is compressed. What format are you really sending? Raw 16-bit signed samples?

Comment: Majenko:  You are correct -- pardon my redundancy.  The MP3 data will come from an iPhone's music library, by WiFi to the Arduino (probably Adafruit Feather M0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the SD card on the shield isn't read by the VS1053 directly, but by the arduino, which sends it to the VS1053.

So as far as I can see, you should be able to do what you want.